# reshape, aggregate how to perform multiple actions on two membership vectors?

Tags: r

I think I've finally got how ask to the question properly...I've tried a bunch of things, and then misspecified the problem around table() which was one thing I was using, though probably not the best thing.
 My problem is how to take two vectors of equal length of factor and membership and get various distributions of factors on group. So, my data looks like "dat"

```
group<-rep(c("a","b","c"), each=4)
mem<-c(1:6,1:3,1:2,1)
dat<-cbind(group,rep)
dat
```

How do I turn it to something with, say, 9 columns and 3 rows, with column 1 for group names, columns 2:7 for the number of members in each group, column 8 for group totals and next columns for some group rates rather than counts - something that look like this:

```
 group mem1 mem2 mem3 mem4 mem5 mem6 total rate1
 a.     1.   1.   1.   1.   0.   0.    4.    0.25
 b.     1.   1.   0.   0.   1.   0.    4.    0.25
 c.     2.   1.   1.   0.   0.   0.    4.    0.5
```

There must be an easy way, right? Much appreciated!!!!

Comment: it should be dat <- cbind(group,mem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is table them:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(dat[,1],dat[,2]))
      1 2 3 4 5 6
    a 1 1 1 1 0 0
    b 1 1 0 0 1 1
    c 2 1 1 0 0 0
```

Once you have this, it's a matter of performing the other calculations:

```
counts = as.data.frame.matrix(table(dat[,1],dat[,2]))
total = rowSums(counts)
rate = sweep(counts,2,total,"/")
colnames(counts) = paste0("mem",colnames(counts))
colnames(rate) = paste0("rate",colnames(rate))
res = data.frame(group=rownames(counts),counts,total=total,rate)
res

  group mem1 mem2 mem3 mem4 mem5 mem6 total rate1 rate2 rate3 rate4 rate5 rate6
a     a    1    1    1    1    0    0     4  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.00  0.00
b     b    1    1    0    0    1    1     4  0.25  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.25  0.25
c     c    2    1    1    0    0    0     4  0.50  0.25  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

Comment: Thank you! I am so embarrassed I didn't get that one can table 2 variables

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah I also realized that sometime later.. we learn by doing right.